# Displaying an array of size 0 if no data is present, instead of array of size 1 (array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }) || PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this below code with three different conditions:

1. `"$json->clientip":["10.78.58.1", "10.75.22.12"]` if the clientip is an array
2. `"$json->clientip":"10.74.10.1, 10.75.10.132, 10.75.10.152"` if clientip is a string separated by comma
3. `"$json->clientip":"10.74.10.1, "` if clientip is a string with Single value

All the three cases is returning an array.

However when i am trying below condition:

```
"$json->clientip":""
```

it is returning me an array of size 1 but i want an array of size of 0 if there is no data. Can someone please help me with the logic or code, how can i do that

```html
    switch (true) {
    case is_array($json->clientip):
        // Ips sent as a JSON array case ..
        // ...                     
        foreach ($json->clientip as $key => $ipValue) {
            $requestObj->clientip[] = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP, ((trim($ipValue)) ?? FALSE) )) ? trim($ipValue):NULL;
        }
        break;
        
    default:
        
        if (strpos($json->clientip, ',')) {
            // Comma separated IPs case ...
            // ..
            $tmp = explode(',', $json->clientip);
            foreach ($tmp as $key => $ipValue) {
                if (trim($ipValue) != '') $requestObj->clientip[] = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP, ((trim($ipValue)) ?? FALSE) )) ? trim($ipValue):NULL;
            }
        } else {
            // Single value case ..
            // ...
            $requestObj->clientip[] = trim($json->clientip);
        }                 
    } 
    
    var_dump($requestObj->clientip);die;
```

Comment: it should be enough:  `default: $requestObj->clientip = explode(',', trim($json->clientip));`

Comment: Thanks..Can you please elaborate it bit more, how can i use this in my code. A little explanation will be really helpful

Comment: add inside the `default` smth like this `elseif (!trim($json->clientip)) {$requestObj->clientip = [];}`

Comment: @Deadooshka thanks a lot..it is working fine now :)